# laravel 4 multilanguage website

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, multilingual

I'm trying to implement a multilanguage laravel 4 website, with language code in the url ( mywebsite.com/en/home and mywebsite.com/de/home )

I've seen a couple of options like filtering all requests and checking if the first param is one of the language code.

I've also check on packagist but haven't find something that already do tee job.

Is there a better way to implement it?

Thank you

Comment: I've found this code snippet that may help you. It allows you to have multi lang urls: https://gist.github.com/jacekd/4562959

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I've create a config variable in config/app.php

```
'available_language' => array('en', 'fr', 'es'),
```

In filters.php I detect the browser language:

```
Route::filter('detectLang', function($lang = "auto")
{
    if($lang != "auto" && in_array($lang , Config::get('app.available_language')))
    {
        Config::set('app.locale', $lang);
    }else{
        $browser_lang = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? strtok(strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), ',') : '';
        $browser_lang = substr($browser_lang, 0,2);
        $userLang = (in_array($browser_lang, Config::get('app.available_language'))) ? $browser_lang : Config::get('app.locale');
        Config::set('app.locale', $userLang);
    }
});
```

and then in routes.php I can either detect the language or force it:

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'before' => 'detectLang()', // auto-detect language
    function(){
        ...
    })
);
```

or

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'before' => 'detectLang("fr")', // force language to "fe"
    function(){
        ...
    })
);
```

Comment: Once you implemented almost the complete The Shift Exchange's suggestion you should give to him some credit...

Comment: Well I don't see any implementation of Shift suggestion. Oh sorry. I'm using sessions. :)

Comment: What about the language code in the URL? This is what the question is about…

Answer (score 1):

You could set a language variable in the user session.

Then use a '`before`' filter, and view that variable, and log the correct language file.

If there is no variable set - then use a default (perhaps based upon their IP location).

Comment: this is a bad SEO practice, as search engines doesn't have sessions, so the content will be always indexed in the same language